# How to use a CTE on multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Date Table like this one:

```
Exit_Date     Date_ID
2017-05-31     1
2017-04-26     2
2017-01-02     3
2016-12-24     4
2016-11-27     5
```

I use a loop to insert each of those Dates into a CTE to generates the last 15 years of these dates like this:

```
declare @DI int = 1
declare @d date
while @DI <=5
begin
select @d = Exit_Date from Date_Table where Date_ID = @DI
declare @EDTable table (Exit_Date  Date);
with
  a as(
    select dateadd(yy,-1,@d) d,0 i
      union all
    select dateadd(yy,-1,d),i+1 from a where i<14
  ),
  b as(select d,datediff(dd,0,d)%7 dd from a)
 insert into @EDTable select d from b;
  set @DI = @DI + 1
 end
```

The results are correct, I get 75 rows with my dates. I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of the `WHILE` loop by replacing variable `@d` by each date record from Date_Table?

Comment: If you have working code that already produces the results you want, but are seeking improvements, this may be a better fit on Code Review rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you I did not know the existence of Code Review

Comment: Look into a CROSS APPLY to eliminate the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your loop with a numbers table, or adhoc numbers table like so:

```
;with numbers as (
  select top (15)
    i = row_number() over (order by (select 1))
  from [master]..spt_values
)
select Exit_Date = dateadd(year,-1*i,d.Exit_Date)
from Date_Table d
  cross join numbers n
where d.Date_id >= 1
  and d.Date_id <= 5
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/AQEZ43941

---

This method outperforms a recursive solution, especially as the number of rows increase.

Reference:

- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just use the table in the the recursive CTE:

```
create table #DateTable (
    Date_ID int primary key not null,
    Exit_Date date not null
);

insert into #DateTable (Exit_Date, Date_ID) values
('2017-05-31',1),
('2017-04-26',2),
('2017-01-02',3),
('2016-12-24',4),
('2016-11-27',5);

declare @EDTable table (Exit_Date  Date);

;with a as (
    select dateadd(yy,-1,Exit_Date) d,0 i from #DateTable where Date_ID between 1 and 5
    union all
    select dateadd(yy,-1,d),i+1 from a where i<14
)
,b as (
    select d,datediff(dd,0,d)%7 dd from a
)
insert into @EDTable
select d from b;
```